# Abort merge using JGit

Tags: git, jgit

This is pretty straightforward: How do I simulate the command 
`git merge --abort` in JGit? I need to "preview" the conflicts prior to the real merge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent for `git merge --abort` in JGit. This code snippet may serve as a starting point:

```java
// clear the merge state
repository.writeMergeCommitMsg(null);
repository.writeMergeHeads(null);

// reset the index and work directory to HEAD
Git.wrap(repository).reset().setMode(ResetType.HARD).call();
```

It empties the merge state files and then resets index and work directory to the contents of the current HEAD commit.

In order to test if two commits can be merged, you could also use an *in-core merger*. This would avoid checking out the conflicting commit into the work directory just to reset them later on.

```java
RevCommit parentCommit = mergeCommit.getParent(0);
revWalk.parseHeaders(parentCommit);

ResolveMerger merger = (ResolveMerger) MergeStrategy.RESOLVE.newMerger(repository, true);
merger.setWorkingTreeIterator(new FileTreeIterator(repository));
merger.setBase(parentCommit.getTree());
if (!merger.merge(headCommit, mergeCommit)) {
  if (merger.failed()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Should not happen with in-core mergers");
  }
  // inspect merger.getMergeResults() for further details
}
```

Comment: Is "mergeCommit" FETCH_HEAD?

Comment: `mergeCommit` is the commit that should be merged into HEAD.