# Can't get out of REBASING_MERGE state with JGit

Tags: jgit

I am using JGit (v4.10.0.201712302008-r) to automate tasks that interact with our git repository.

Some of the tasks leave the repo in a `REBASING_MERGE` state for some reason. Now the next time I process a task, I need to try to "repair" the repository. I have already removed potential conflicted/modified/added but the repo is still in `REBASING_MERGE` state.

I've tried what is mention [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807016/abort-merge-using-jgit) (aborting a merge), but to no avail - the repository status is still the same and I can't do a pull:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.WrongRepositoryStateException: Cannot pull into a repository with state: REBASING_MERGE
```

Any idea of how to fix this with JGit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer here : https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/RebaseToOriginMaster.java#L78 (I adapted the code) :

```java
 if(!result.getStatus().isSuccessful()) {
 // if rebasing stopped or failed, you can get back to the original state by running it with setOperation(RebaseCommand.Operation.ABORT)
    result = git.rebase().setUpstream("origin/master").setOperation(RebaseCommand.Operation.ABORT).call();
    System.out.println("Aborted rebase with state: " + result.getStatus() + ": " + result.getConflicts());
 }
```

I still need to understand why rebase failed, because there were no conflicts initially.

Comment: To understand why rebase failed, you may want to inspect the `RebaseResult` returned by `RebaseCommand::call`.

Answer (score 1):

Some commands check the repository state returned from `Repository::getRepositoryState` before proceeding.

The `REBASING_MRGE` state is returned if there is a file or directory `rebase-merge` in the `.git` directory. If you are sure that it's safe to return to the normal state, you can just delete the fire/directory.

Comment: yeah, I thought about it, but I wanted to avoid it, so that I don't have to checkout again the whole repo.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why would you have to checkout again? For the PullCommand to work you would need a repository already.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear - I tried cleaning the local repository by doing git.status().call() and resetting the conflicted/added files, and reverting the modified ones. Maybe I was missing something, but the overall status was still REBASING_MERGE. So I thought that worst case, I would be able to delete the local repository and check out a fresh copy.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.