# JGIT Repeated Merge Conflict Null pointer exception

Tags: java, git, nullpointerexception, jgit

I would like to ask regarding the below code lines why i get null pointer Exception. Is this something Git related which i don't understand ?

```
refsideMerge=existingRepo.exactRef("refs/heads/sideMerge");
tmpMerge = git.merge();
tmpMerge.include(refsideMerge);
tmpMerge.setCommit(false);//dry run to get conflicting files
tmpMergeRes = tmpMerge.call();

Map allConflicts = tmpMergeRes.getConflicts();          
 for (Map.Entry<String,int[][]> entry : tmpMergeRes.getConflicts().entrySet()) {
 System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey());
  for(int[] arr : entry.getValue()) {
   System.out.println("value: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
  }
}
```

Description:

After Repeatedly running this code snippet i bump into Nullpointer exception.
I want to test my xml Parsing for Merge Conflicts that's why i need repeated Merge Conflicts to handle. Currently only the Merge part is used to generate conflicts.

As far as i realized it stops at the below line

```
Map allConflicts = tmpMergeRes.getConflicts();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Explanations i found for this:

Basically whenever you run git merge it will touch the working directory even if its dry run as its written [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option).

There are 2 possible solutions:
[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807016/abort-merge-using-jgit), [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736517/how-to-hard-reset-from-one-git-branch-to-other-in-jgit).

For now i will go with resetting the head after dry-run. This is a simple solution, The other solution with ResolveMerger would be better but still investigating how to do it.

```
refsideMerge=existingRepo.exactRef("refs/heads/sideMerge");
tmpMerge = git.merge();
tmpMerge.include(refsideMerge);
tmpMerge.setCommit(false);//dry run to get conflicting files
tmpMergeRes = tmpMerge.call();

Map allConflicts = tmpMergeRes.getConflicts();          
 for (Map.Entry<String,int[][]> entry : tmpMergeRes.getConflicts().entrySet()) {
 System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey());
  for(int[] arr : entry.getValue()) {
   System.out.println("value: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
  }
}
git.reset().setMode(ResetType.HARD).call();
```