# How to call "git checkout -m" using Jgit API?

Tags: java, jgit

I've been searching the JGit API for hours, trying to figure out how to reach a similar behavior to `git checkout -m file`.

What I need is a programmatic way to revert the local repository (or a single file) to the state it was when it had conflicts.

Imagine the following scenario:

1. I have a conflict in 'file1' when trying to merge two branches.
2. I start making changes to 'file1' to solve the conflicts.
3. At some point, I want to discard the changes made on 'file1' and go back to the conflict state, with all conflict 'marks'.

Is it possible to achieve this using JGit API?

Comment: If you don't mind losing all changes, you could abort the entire merge operation as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807016/abort-merge-using-jgit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RüdigerHerrmann. Unfortunately, I need to reset to the state after the merge operation was performed i.e. the conflict state. Returning to the state pre-merge would imply that I need to make the merge again. However, I cannot be sure about which merge algorithm was used to generate the conflict. My initial stage is the point where there are already conflicts in the project. Thanks anyway.